# Parameterized bean in CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm trying to create a CDI bean with parameters. My problem is that I want these parameters to be passed by the injecting class. How can I do that?

e.g.

```
class MyBean() {

}

@Dependent
class MyInjectingClass() {
   @Inject MyBean myBean; // and somehow add two int parameters here that MyBean will use in its methods
}
```

Comment: Can can provide a procuder method with `@Produces` if applicable.

Comment: could you please write me a really simple example? I don't really get it how could it help me.

Comment: I think injection is done on first use of myBean. You can try to set Parameters in a @PostConstruct-Method in MyInjectingClass.

Answer (score 1):

If the `int`s are entirely related just to the production of `MyBean`, then you can write a [producer method](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#declaring_producer_method) that makes an instance of `MyBean` however it likes.  For example:

```
@ApplicationScoped // the "host" of a producer method must itself be a bean
class WhereverYouWantTheProducerMethodToLive {

  @Produces
  @Dependent // make MyBean instances in @Dependent scope
  private MyBean makeMyBean() {
    return new MyBean(1, 2);
  }

}
```